# The Microsoft Jet Database Engine Stopped The Process Because You And Another User

Tags: ms-access

The Microsoft Jet Database Engine Stopped The Process Because You And Another User

how to solve this problem in ms acess.

Comment: Please provide more detail. Is this a single user or multi-user database? What kind of solution are you looking for? Do you wish to warn a second user that the record is already being updated? Are you updating in code and manually at the same time? Some code would be nice.

Comment: Is there more to the error message that's been cut off?

Answer (score -1):

This problem is usually caused by mixing Access's default bound form editing with SQL updates. For instance, if you have a record in a form, and edit its data, and then run a SQL UPDATE that alters the same record, you'll get this error message, because you had an editing session opened in the form, and then you've tried to edit via the SQL UPDATE statement.

You should do all your updates in the bound form itself, and not use SQL UPDATEs.

But if you feel it's necessary (it almost never is), the way to avoid the error is to save the record before you run your SQL update:

```
  If Me.Dirty Then
     Me.Dirty = False
  End If
  CurrentDB.Execute("[SQL UPDATE statement]")
```

But again, let me stress that having to do this is generally an indication that you have a design error, one that's often made by refugees from other development platforms failing to comprehend the ease of use of Access bound forms.

Comment: People who downvote really should explain why they do so. I assume it's because somebody's fee-fees were hurt by the last paragraph.